# ClassNotFoundException thrown when compiling basic Hello World Program

Tags: java, windows-7, javac, java-6

I am just trying to compile and run a very simple test program, but it simply will not work, and I have no idea what the problem is.

I have a java project that's been heaped on me, and I know little to nothing about java. Especially compiling from the windows command line.

I have two Jars that I need to compile a simple "hello world" program with.

Here's my "build.bat"

```
C:\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\javac -cp "C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test";"C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\test1.jar";"C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\test2.jar"; "C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\sample.java"
```

Then, I:

```
C:\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\java sample
```

This spits back the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sample
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   sample
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)

No matter how I set up my classpath, I cannot for the life of me get this HELLO WORLD program to run.

Can someone please help me out? I'm pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also specify the classpath for the interpreter to locate your class:

```
java -classpath "C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test";"C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\test1.jar";"C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\test2.jar"; Sample
```

This would run your class from any working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Run your program from the directory with the class in it:

`C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\>java sample`

CLASSPATH (normally) includes the current directory.

If you have "sample.class" in the current directory, and you also need classes in test1.jar and test2.jar, this should work:

`java -cp "test1.jar;test2.jar;." sample`

Comment: The working directory was the C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\> directory. Didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Java's case sensitive.  Is your class named "sample" or "Sample"?

Answer (score 0):

Afer running this command

C:\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\javac -cp "C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test";"C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\test1.jar";"C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\test2.jar"; "C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\sample.java"

It would have created a .class file at this location "C:\Users\FREYERA\Desktop\Test\". i.e. sample.class

You need to either go to this folder location and run your java command to execute the program. Make sure that your "JAVA_HOME" environment variable is set.

Or you can copy the sample.class file to "C:\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\" folder and run the command.